# Getting infinite loop when reading file from method

Tags: java, file, methods, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

I am trying to refactor my code, and adding methods where possible. When I read a file from a method and return the result of the computation, the code goes into extreme memory consumption, infinite loop.

My modification looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberOfLines {
    public static int compute () {
        // read this file
        String theFile = "numbers.txt";

        Scanner fileRead = null;

        if (NumberOfLines.class.getResourceAsStream(theFile) != null) {
            fileRead = new Scanner(NumberOfLines.class.getResourceAsStream(theFile));
        }           
        else {
            System.out.print("The file " + theFile + " was not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Checkpoint: I am stuck here");

        // count number of lines
        int totalLines = 0;
        while(fileRead.hasNextInt()) {
            totalLines++;

        }
        fileRead.close();
        return totalLines;

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println("The total number of lines is: " + compute());


    }
}
```

If instead of writing the method, and placing the code on main, then it works. Why is this?

**EDIT**

Contents of *numbers.txt* is:

```
5 
2
7
4
9
1
5
9
69
5
2
5
6
10
23
5
36
5
2
8
9
6
```

So I expect out put to be:

The total number of lines is: 22

Comment: Add `System.out.println(fileRead.next())` inside the while loop to check what you're reading. See if it matches the text file.

Comment: You are right. It works. I had missed the break of the while loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are getting stuck in an infinite loop is because you are reading the file but not incrementing the scanners token in the while loop. So the while *condition* is always true.

```
while (fileRead.hasNextInt()) {
    totalLines++;
    fileRead.nextInt();  // change made here only
}
```